# yii2 error when useFileTransport is false

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, swiftmailer

i want to use the swiftmailer in my project. I want to send the email to the new user after admin register the new user.

the problem is when i used **'useFileTransport' => false** it will give this error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ymwM.png)

its does not prompt any error if i use **'useFileTransport' => true** but the email does not send. it is only save in the runtime/mail

this is my code for swiftmailer at (common/config/main-local.php)

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',

    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'username' => 'support@example.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'port' => '587',
        'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
],
```

this is my code for send email at controller

```
public function actionSignup()
{
    $model = new SignupForm();
    Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setTo($model->email)
        ->setFrom('admin@gmail.com')
        ->setSubject('REGISTRATION')
        ->setTextBody($model->username)
        ->send();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($user = $model->signup()) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
    }
    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```

can you show me where i did wrong ? sorry if this just stupid question. i'm new to yii2..

Comment: are you testing this on your local pc or on a domain.

Comment: on my local pc. i use xampp localhost. is it impossible to use swiftmailer in own pc ?

Comment: whats in your `php.ini` for the `SMTP` and `smtp_port` values?

Comment: also are you on windows or ubuntu ?

Comment: i'm sorry but it seem like i cannot find any file name php.ini.perhaps can you give me any clue where this file are ?. i'm not doing any change to any file except my common/config/main-local.php since i install the swiftmailer extension using cmd

Comment: i'm using windows

Comment: open your `localhost/xampp` and click `phpinfo` link in the left menu and look at the `loaded Configuration` path see this [image](https://imgur.com/a/SS4C0sS)

Comment: i found this in my php.ini for smtp and smtp value **[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=25**

Comment: i try to to change **'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '25',** it work when useFileTransport= false but it give this error **Connection could not be established with host localhost [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
#10061]**